# Root of unity paradox

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose $w$ is a cube root of unity. Then we know that $w^3 =1$. now suppose we want the value of $w^4$.

$w^4 = (w^3)^{4/3} = 1^{4/3} = 1$ which is obviously false

Why does this happen?

Comment: Because the (complex) $\;\frac43$-th root of one is *not* necessarily one...Do it this way: $$w^3=1\implies w^4=w(w^3)=w\cdot 1=w$$

Comment: But 1 raised to any other no. is one itself

Comment: No user, it might not be *within the complex number field*

Comment: By the same logic you'd have $$w^3 = 1 \Rightarrow w = 1^{\frac{1}{3}} = 1$$ which is nonsense.